# Menu icon not appearing on ActionBarActvity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am trying to add the following menu to my ActionBarActivity class. Here is the menu XML.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Logout"/> 
</menu>
```

And this file is inflated from the activity class

```
public class TestClass extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
    } 
}
```

The app has to support version 2.3 and above. So,

```
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

Unfortunately, the action items are not appearing. Instead they are added inside the overflow button.

Having read through google docs and various developer posts, I could hardly find what's going wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried that in a device? Sometimes emulator will not show the menu in action bar if hardware button is present.

Comment: Im running it on Nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

Try change xml into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
```

I have done this like that in my project and works

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line for icon here:

```
MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_share_default);
```